# RadioButtonFor in a for loop for a model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Problem is simple, I have a partial view whose model is a list. I am trying to bind radio buttons for a boolean parameter for each item in the list. Only one item in the list can be selected, hence the radio buttons. The model is correctly binding for all other parameters EXCEPT for the boolean that should be bound to the radio button. The following code below is a truncated version of my partial.

NOTE - I need to use the "BeginRouteForm" helper because of multiple routings that my app has. Also I am using a "for" loop instead of a "foreach" cause it seems as if foreach did not properly bound my model when sending it off to the controller.:

```
@model TestListModel
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("Default", new { action = "Submit", controller = "TheController" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "DoSomething" })) {
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count(); i ++) {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.List[i].Id)
            <tr>
                <td>
            @{
                Dictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                attributes.Add("Name", "test");
                attributes.Add("id", "");
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.List[i].Id, attributes)
            }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" />
}
```

**UPDATE:** Ok so I am dumb (probably being end of day and all) but I was modeling my radiobuttons as if they were a checkboxlist. Explains why the binding was incorrectly working. I updated the code above to my new code now I am using a model with a "selectedid" instead of an IEnumerable. Problem is, it's still not working

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following solved it.

```
attributes.Add("Name", "test");
```

Comment: Can simply be `@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.List[i].Id, new { id = "" })` :)

Comment: Ya that can work to. 

I used the attributes dictionary cause there were additional attributes that I was changing that I left out when I wrote my question.